# Do we know how Feynmans religious views changed throughout his life?

Tags: physics, biographical-details, social-context

According to Feynman, there was a quota for Jews at American Universities and when he was accepted on a graduate programme - I think at Princeton - they were told "he's Jewish but he doesn't act like one", with the impression that this was said approvingly. I think this was part of anecdote in one of his popular books. (When I read that as a teenager, I sat up and took notice, because it made me think about the so-called 'freedoms' of the United States in the modern era. After all, I knew about the slavery and how it had been gotten rid of by courageous men and women. But this showed me that there was still a dark underbelly where one might least expect it).

I'm under the impression that Feynman was more or less agnostic to athiest. So what prompted his, I take, late soul searching in his lecture *On the Meaning of it All*, where he explains that he saw the world in a new way and that Christianity was a great faith? This lecture never seems to be mentioned by his fan club - which I take to be atheist to a man and woman, generally speaking. If Feynman was alive, and given his views, I expect him to walk right pass them.

**Q. When was this quota imposed - presumably it was an informal one. And when was this lifted?**

**Q. What led to his religious awakening? Is this clarified in any of his later writings or conversations with friends?**

I've written the above from memory, so some of the details may be a bit skewy, but the main thrust of it is correct.

Comment: Can you link to that lecture?

Comment: Feynman is dead, and his world-view is an objectively answerable thing, making this question on-topic. Although the question might look a little bit tendentious one (probably he was agnosticist in his entire life, possibly sympathizing with Christianity on a moral level). To use "religious awakening" and similars is only reasonable in the question if there is some link or other reference suggesting that.

Comment: The first question is easily answered by googling. Re the second question, I haven't seen any evidence that Feynman had a "religious awakening."